# nexus 3: get more than 9999 artifacts

Tags: rest, curl, nexus3

I'm querying all artifacts using the Nexus API "curl -u username:pw -X GET 'https://xxx.xxx/service/rest/v1/search?repository=xxx&group=xxx'" under a huge Nexus raw repository with more than 200000 artifacts.
It works well with small directories, but after the 9999th artifact, I get the error:

nested: QueryPhaseExecutionException[Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10050]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level parameter.]; }

I won't be able change the limit size, is there any way that I can get all the artifacts?